# How to issue GET request and parse result to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parsing, filehelpers

Data contains place_id and other columns:

```
place_id    name    city    address ..
133 place1  Laagri  Born 12 ..
161 place2  Mourdi  Karve 12  ..
```

Data is avaliable in 5 different formats. All those urls return same data:

```
http://www.smartpost.ee/places.html
http://www.smartpost.ee/places.xml
http://www.smartpost.ee/places.csv
http://www.smartpost.ee/places.js
http://www.smartpost.ee/places.php
```

One of urls should selected to get data. Data may change so it should not cached.
How to issue http GET requet and create two element List: first element is place_id from first column and second element is concatenated name, city and address field. Something like:

```
class DeliveryList {
   public string Id, Address;
  }

List<DeliveryList> res= GetAndParse("http://www.smartpost.ee/places.csv", 
    "place_id, name+\" \"+ city +\" \" + address" );
```

How to implement GetAndParse ? Should http request saved to sting and filehelpers used to parse it ?  Expression `"place_id, name+\" \"+ city +\" \" + address"` can hard-coded in code instead of passing as parameter.

Using ASP.NET MVC4, .NET 4, C# . Code should run in MVC4 controller in server.

Comment: What is the format of your returned data?

Comment: You can open those links in browser to see the data. http://www.smartpost.ee/places.csv is comma delimited.

Comment: You want to parse all of them, or only one format is enough?

Comment: One format is enough. Best suitable format can selected from those formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use XML endpoint and implement deserialization to array of places as implemented below:

```
public static class PlacesHelper
{
    private const string EndpointUrl = "http://www.smartpost.ee/places.xml";

    /// <summary> Load array of places </summary>
    public static async Task<Places> LoadPlacesAsync()
    {
        var xmlString = await HttpRequestHelper.DownloadStringAsync(EndpointUrl);
        return SerializationHelper.DeserializeXmlString<Places>(xmlString);
    }
}

public static class SerializationHelper
{
    /// <summary> Deserializes Xml string of type T. </summary>
    public static T DeserializeXmlString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        T tempObject = default(T);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xmlString)))
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
            var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            tempObject = (T) xs.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }

        return tempObject;
    }

    /// <summary> Convert String to Array </summary>
    private static Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(String xmlString)
    {
        return new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(xmlString);
    }
}

public static class HttpRequestHelper
{
    /// <summary> Download String Async </summary>
    public static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string uri)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("places_info", Namespace = "")]
public class Places
{
    [XmlElement("place", typeof(Place), Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public Place[] Place { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Place
{
    [XmlElement("place_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var arrayOfPlaces = await PlacesHelper.LoadPlacesAsync();
```

So, you will get an array of places (id, name, city, address).

**UPDATE:**

For .NET Framework 4 Microsoft released the [Async Targeting Pack (Microsoft.Bcl.Async)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx) through [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). So Install the package 'Microsoft Async' from Nuget and you will be able to use async/await.

Example implementation of controller action:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public async Task<object> GetPlaces()
    {
        return Json(await PlacesHelper.LoadPlacesAsync(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why asunc is used? This is single thread and normal sync method can used, isn't it ?  Data is in flat table. Maybe parsing it in csv format is simpler and csv format should used ?

Comment: You wrote "Code should run in MVC4 controller in server.". It's a better way to use asyc action methods in a controller for long-runing task such as loading xml from a remote server. You could read more detailed information here  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Line `await HttpRequestHelper.DownloadStringAsync(EndpointUrl)` causes compile error `'Task<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<string>' could be found` . Question states that target framework is .NET 4. How to fix this ?

Comment: Async/Await is a feature of .Net Framework 4.5. Could you upgrade your solution to use this version or should I help you to implement the async code for the .Net Framework 4?

Comment: Code should run in Windows 2003 server. How to support it if upgraded to .NET 4.5 ? If upgrade is not possible, then yes, how to implement this is .NET 4 ? Also DownloadAsStringAsync returns non-ascii characters incorrectly. How to get proper unicode characters to string ? AnhTriet answer works in NET 4, should this used or can something async used in .NET 4 MVC 4 controller also ?

Comment: Updated my post. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

I choose XML format to parse data, using `XmlSerializer`. Here is the code.

**Classes represent our XML data:** the code is self-explained

```
[XmlRoot("places_info")]
public class PlacesInfo
{
    [XmlElement("place")]
    public Place[] Places { get; set; }
}

public class Place
{
    [XmlElement("place_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Your `Delivery` class:**

```
public class Delivery
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Delivery(string id, string address)
    {
        Id = id;
        Address = address;
    }
}
```

**Code to get and parse data:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get XML string from web
    var client = new WebClient();

    // Set encoding for non-ASCII characters
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    string xml = client.DownloadString("http://www.smartpost.ee/places.xml");

    // Create a serializer
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlacesInfo));

    // Variable to hold all XML data
    PlacesInfo info;

    // Deserialize XML string to object
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
    {
        info = (PlacesInfo) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    // Create delivery list
    var deliveryList = new List<Delivery>();

    // For each place
    foreach (var place in info.Places)
    {
        // Concatenate name, city, and address
        string address = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", place.Name, place.City, place.Address);

        // Add new delivery
        var delivery = new Delivery(place.Id, address);
        deliveryList.Add(delivery);

        // Display to test
        Console.WriteLine(delivery.Id + " " + delivery.Address);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I put comment in the code carefully. If you find something hard to understand, feel free to let me know. Hope this help :)

Comment: In string returned by `DownloadString` non-ascii characters appear as two stange characters in. How to get non-ascii characters properly, as single unicode character ? If xml link is opened directly in browser they are correct.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem. Why you dont use async to improve MVC perfomance like in Yuriy A. answer?  I marked you answer as answer since it provides client.Encoding setting.

Comment: Because the main point of your question is about getting and parsing data, not async task. I keep the code simple, easy to understand, then you can optimize it as you see fit :)

Comment: Thank you, great answer especially for encoding setting. However Yuriy A. contains also async usage for both MVC 4 and MVC 4.5 . It looks like this is reasonable and adds value so I marked it as answer. Sorry for that. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Never mind. I agree with you. Yuriy A did a good job in dealing with async task. If you want to know why he did that, take a look at this great [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Happy to help :)